# Ant modifying property file but escaping characters

Tags: ant

I have an ant build script that is modifying a properties file.  When it amends the properties with the new paths, it seems to escape the back slashes and colons.  I understand this is probably working as intended but batch files use this property file further down the process and it is causing errors.

Is there an ant solution to this, or should I start looking at a shell script workaround?

Thanks,
BON

**Ant target**:

```
    <target name="modify_workstation_properties" depends="loadWinEnvVars, loadUnixEnvVars">
    <propertyfile file="${basedir}/Deliverables/config/framework_setup/workstation.properties">
        <entry key="toplevel.project.dir" value="${basedir}"/>
        <entry key="root.project.dir" value="${basedir}/Construction"/>
        <entry key="root.dir" value="${basedir}/Framework/Construction/netc_os"/>
        <entry key="jdk.home" value="${JDKHome}"/>
        <entry key="wls.home" value="${WLSHome}"/>
        <entry key="domain.dir" value="${DomainDir}"/>
        <entry key="stage.dir" value="${DomainDir}"/>
    </propertyfile>
</target>
```

**Output:**

```
# Top Level Root directory of the new working project
toplevel.project.dir=C\:\\forImage\\r16_dev_deploy

# Root directory of the new working project
root.project.dir=C\:\\forImage\\r16_dev_deploy/Construction

# Root directory of the framework project
root.dir=C\:\\forImage\\r16_dev_deploy/Framework/Construction/netc_os
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't modify the way that the properties are written. However after the file is written you could use the [ReplaceRegExp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task and correct the escaped characters.

Comment: I ended up echoing the properties to a new file, then used concat to join new file to the properties file.  This worked, looks like your option would work too! Thanks