# property file path changed during ant build

Tags: ant

```
<propertyfile file="${build.dir}/MyProperties.properties">
            <entry key="releaseInformation"
                type="string"
                value="${build.time}"/>
</propertyfile>
```

When Ant copies my properties file over to the bin directory there is a property in it that has something like "samplePathName=C\:\Users\SomeUser\". But the property from the original file was "samplePathName=C:\Users\SomeUser\". How would the additional backslash end up there? I don't see anything that could possibly cause this to happen. Where should I begin looking other than the build.xml which only contains (relevant) the above line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ant modifying property file but escaping characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428416/ant-modifying-property-file-but-escaping-characters)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem - the format of property files is defined by [Sun (Oracle)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29). Ant is conforming to this, which is why the escaping happens.  There's no way round this using the `propertyfile` task - that's the way it's intended to work.  If the file is genuinely a Java property file, then it shouldn't matter - the escaping should be handled correctly when the file is read.

However if you are hoping to use `propertyfile` to write a name-value config file that's for something else - where the escaping is not wanted - you'll need to adopt a different approach.  As mentioned in the [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428416/ant-modifying-property-file-but-escaping-characters/7431135#7431135) - you might use the Ant [`replace`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) or `replaceregexp` tasks for this.